# red borders are not coming outside of input types while error in angular

Tags: angular

app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { InputFormatDirective } from './input-format.directive';
    import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form/contact-form.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        InputFormatDirective,
        ContactFormComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

contact-form.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms'

    @Component({
      selector: 'contact-form',
      templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css']
    })
    export class ContactFormComponent {
      form = new FormGroup({
        username: new FormControl('', [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3)

        ]),
        password: new FormControl('',[
          Validators.required
        ])
      });

      get username(){
        return this.form.get('username');
      }
      get password(){
        return this.form.get('password');
      }
    }
```

contact-form.component.html

```
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input
            formControlName="username"
            id="username" 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
        />
        <div *ngIf="username.touched && username.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="username.errors.required">
                Username required
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="username.errors.minlength">
                    Username should be min {{ username.errors.minlength.requiredLength }} char
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Passowrd</label>
        <input
            formControlName="password"
            id="password"
            type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
        />
        <div *ngIf="password.touched && password.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
                Password Required
        </div>
      </div>
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
```

Here i am adding angular custom validations.
It is working for error messages but my **borders** **of input types not becomes red.**

I found the same this from one tutorial but the **red borders** outside is not coming.

Please have a look into my code.

**I want red borders outside input types.**

Comment: try this in your styles `.ng-invalid { border: 1px solid red; }`

Comment: Not working bro.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your style.css;

```
.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(form) , .ng-invalid.ng-dirty:not(form){ 
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

**Other way**

In your style.css;

```
.invalid-input{
border-color:red !important;
}
```

and on your inputs:

```
<input [class.invalid-input]="password.touched && password.invalid" formControlName="password" id="password" type="text" class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: I did not understand what you said. By default, you want the border color to be red? Or are you talking about something different? @soubhagya

Comment: No. I think in custom validation automatically border should become red or we need to make it customly

Comment: Okey, i understand you. I found this, maybe it'il work; .ng-invalid.ng-touched , .ng-invalid.ng-dirty{ 
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

Comment: And here is a my working sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zh9y8i @soubhagya

Comment: PLease check above url

Comment: I added this on your  style.css, and it's working: .ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(form) , .ng-invalid.ng-dirty:not(form){ 
    border: 3px solid red;
} https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9de3ym what is wrong?